# How to pass parameter to Android AsyncTask

Tags: android

My question is how to pass parameter to AsyncTask dynamically. How I do this?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.daily_download);

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    strBusinessUnit = myPrefs.getString("BusinessUnit", "");
    strExecutive = myPrefs.getString("Executive", "");
    strTerritoryCode = myPrefs.getString("TerritoryCode", "");

    tableListGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.dailydownloadgrid);
    tableListGrid.setAdapter(new TableListImageAdapter(this));
    tableListGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                dailyDownTable = "LoadTarget";
                jsonFilter = "Target1";
                new DailyDownldAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });
}



    public class DailyDownldAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        // private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DailyDownloadActivity.this);
         int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            //if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            //  this.dialog.dismiss();
            //}
            //Toast.makeText(DailyDownloadActivity.this,"Download successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

         // this.dialog.setMessage("Downloading Table Data.......");
         // this.dialog.show();
         // myProgress = 0;
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          new DownlaodTableActivity().loadDailyDownloadData(dailyDownTable,jsonFilter,strBusinessUnit, strBusinessUnit,strTerritoryCode);
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
         // dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
      }
 }
```

I commented 'ProgressDialog ' & run the code also I got error
Here `loadDailyDownloadDatadailyDownTable,jsonFilter,strBusinessUnit, strBusinessUnit,strTerritoryCode)` method i want to pass parameter.

When I run this code I got error :

```
     08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:680)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at com.xont.controller.syn.DownlaodTableActivity.<init>(DownlaodTableActivity.java:62)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at com.xont.controller.admin.DailyDownloadActivity$DailyDownldAsyncTask.doInBackground(DailyDownloadActivity.java:83)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at com.xont.controller.admin.DailyDownloadActivity$DailyDownldAsyncTask.doInBackground(DailyDownloadActivity.java:1)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-19 09:22:15.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Please help me ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: "DownlaodTableActivity()" whats this...? is that an Activity..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem you need to read the document for AsyncTask more first. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Crashing problem:**

Keep in mind that doInBackground will be executed in background thread. The crashing problem you are seeing is that DownlaodTableActivity is instantiated inside a background thread, which is IMPOSSIBLE in Android framework. (Has nothing to do with parameters passing by the way) All activities must be instantiated in the main UI thread. The Looper.prepare() will be called if you have instantiated it in UI thread.

**Solution:** move loadDailyDownloadData to a different class that does not depend on DownlaodTableActivity. If you want to the UI to be updated in DownlaodTableActivity, do it in UI thread after you download the data.

**Parameter passing:**

```
strBusinessUnit = myPrefs.getString("BusinessUnit", "");
strExecutive = myPrefs.getString("Executive", "");
strTerritoryCode = myPrefs.getString("TerritoryCode", "");
... ...
new DailyDownldAsyncTask().execute(dailyDownTable, jsonFilter, strBusinessUnit, strExecutive, strTerritoryCode);
... ...

public class DailyDownldAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        // private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DailyDownloadActivity.this);
         int myProgress;

... ...

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
dailyDownloadData(params[0],params[1],params[2], params[3],params[4];
       return null;
      }
... ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First line of your error list says,your activity is not running.Your activity is not in foreground.Your code will work fine when your activity is in foreground.But will produce this bug when leave your activity.

```
08-19 09:03:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4054b808 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Comment: Please tell me What i want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be error in your passing parameter & `AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>` Here you say void type....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the names of your functions, it sounds like you're trying to download things automatically in the background using AsyncTask.  This isn't really what AsyncTask is intended for - it's for doing things in the background of an active user interface.  I think what you really want to use is a Service with its own Thread, and launch the Service using an Intent sent by the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).